# adding CALayer to UIView with ability to redraw on orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, core-graphics

I have a UIView subclass that is assigned to the `backgroundView` of a UITableVieCell. In my UIView subclass i am adding 2 CALayers in the `initWithFrame:` method.

On orientation change, the height of cells change and i need to readjust the positions of my CALayers; basically redraw.

Since the CALayers are added in the `initWithFrame:` method I cant redraw them by calling `setNeedsDisplay`.

I am new to working with CALayers and dont know what is the right way to do this. How can I add my CALayers in a way to have them redraw on orientation change/or any event that could change the dimensions in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `UIView` subclass implement the `- (void)layoutSubviews;` method. This is called by the framework when the geometry of views changes. You can make the appropriate changes to your layers there.

In CoreAnimation, if you are subclassing layers there is also a `layoutSublayers` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: although i ended up overriding `drawRect:` and doing it in a completely different way, I've tried your way and it works. Thanks for the help, well keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, an easier way would be to use KVO to observe for changes to the view layer's bounds property.

```
[self.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:0 context:nil];
```

Then do whatever you need in your `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method.

Don't forget to `removeObserver:self` when you're done.